# lftp - restart position

Tags: bash, networking, ftp, lftp

When trying to mirror using `lftp` I receive the following output (`-d` debugging mode):

```
<--- 227 Entering Passive Mode {some numbers}
---- Connecting data socket to (more numbers and port)
---- Data connection established
---> REST 0
<--- 350 Restart position accepted (0).
---> RETR {some filename}
```

When I open this file, the file is corrupted - the content of the file is shifted down by several lines and then on top of it a normal copy of the file is written. For example, if file had five lines (line breaks not shown for compactness): line1 line2 line3 line4 line5, then the corrupted file would read: line1 line2 line3 line3 line4 line5.

Given the other problems I am experiencing with this ftp/network combination, I understand that this is not `lftp`'s fault. However, I wonder if disabling `restart position` changes would somehow fix those corrupted files (at least it works for the other files). By reading the manual I can see these two options:

```
   hftp:use-range (boolean)
          when true, lftp will use Range header for transfer restart.

   http:use-range (boolean)
          when true, lftp will use Range header for transfer restart.
```

I don't know if this is relevant to what I am trying to achieve (force `lftp` to always download the data in full, without restarting position), or whether what I want is achievable in principle. I would try these options by actually running them, but I cannot see any predictable pattern in when files get corrupted and re-downloading the same files always gives the correct version. So any help is appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the solution, but based on logs I think that the problem for me was caused by `get -c` commands, so I removed `--continue` from the mirror job.